# Double integrale

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following region $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 | 9\leq x^2+y^2 \leq 16, y \geq 0\}$. And I need to calculate the following double integrale:

$$\iint_D x\exp(x^2+y^2)dA$$
Using polar coordinates. From a Theorem, I get the following double integrale:

$$\int_0^\pi \int_3^4(r\cdot \cos(\theta)\cdot e^{r^2})rdrd\theta$$

Now when I try to integrate this I get something that isnt defined in $\mathbb R$. And if I switch the integrals, like this :

$$\int_3^4 \int_0^\pi(r\cdot \cos(\theta)\cdot e^{r^2})rd\theta dr$$ I simply get 0. Could anyone tell me if I am doing something wrong?

Comment: the limits for the integral of r should be from 0 to 4 since $0 \leq r^2 \leq 4$. And since the limits on both integrals are numbers and not variables then integrating theta before r as you did won't be a problem. then integrating cos would give sin from 0 to pi. so the result is 0

Comment: I miss typed, it was supposed to be 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are better off not converting to polar.

anyway

The function is odd with respect to $x.$

For every $(x,y)$ in the region $(-x,y)$ is also in the region and $f(x,y) = -f(-x,y)$

And this symmetry means that there is as much of the function below the xy plane as above it.  The integral indeed does equal $0.$

Answer (score 0):

Unless you left something out the bounds on r should be from 0 to 4 because the circles radius does go from 0 to 4. Also it is 0 from what I can see, you can't integrate $r^2e^{r^2}$